# Assign Rspec error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, specifications

I'm trying to follow Mike Hartl's tutorial with `RSpec`. I've reached the password reset integration test, and so far I was doing well. Then I got to the line that said `user = assigns(:user)`

I searched for an answer so here is what I have and my error.

Failures:

> PasswordResets Password resets email input valid email sends password and redirects to root
>        Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:user)).to eq([user])

```
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `user' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::PasswordResets::PasswordResets::EmailInput:0x007fc5d16b0ca8>
 # ./spec/requests/password_resets_spec.rb:26:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe "PasswordResets", type: :request do
 describe "Password resets" do
   before do
     ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
     @valid_user = create(:user)
   end

  describe "unsuccessful password reset" do
    it "flashes danger when email is blank" do
     get new_password_reset_path(@valid_user.id)
     post password_resets_path, params: { password_reset: { email: " " } }
     expect(flash[:danger]).to be_present
     expect(page).to render_template(:new)
   end
 end

  describe "email input" do
    it "valid email sends password and redirects to root" do
      post password_resets_path, params: { password_reset: { email: @valid_user.email } }
      expect(@valid_user.reset_digest).not_to match (@valid_user.reload.reset_digest)
      expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size).to eq(1)
      expect(flash[:info]).to be_present
      expect(page).to redirect_to root_url
      expect(assigns(:user)).to eq([user])
    end
 end
end
end`
```

The tutorial I'm following https://www.railstutorial.org/book/password_reset 12.18

I'm not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test is erroring because you haven't defined a `user` variable at that point in your test. You *have* defined `@valid_user`. My guess is your test would pass if you change:
`expect(assigns(:user)).to eq([user])`
to
`expect(assigns(:user)).to eq(@valid_user)`

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I didn't realize the tutorial was referencing the user I already defined.

Comment: if I continue through the tutorial.

The next line fails, also, but I think it's because I'm using the instance variable @valid_user instead of just user. Does this matter? 

`get edit_password_reset_path(@valid_user.reset_token, email: " ")
expect(page).to redirect_to root_url'

I end up with an error saying ActionController No Route Matches and that my id is nil.

Comment: I suspect you may not have defined the `edit` method in your PasswordResetsController class or that you're missing a `redirect_to root_url` somewhere in your controller, but it's hard to say without seeing your controller code. I would check your code against the code in the 12.16 section of the tutorial. If that doesn't help, submit a new question including your controller code, your spec code, and a couple of things you've already tried. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.